# How to fix delay between wakeup and password entry

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

When booting up my computer, or even just awakening it from a long sleep, it takes a while for me to be able to enter my password. The box is there, but I can't move my mouse or type into the box. My screen is frozen. It usually lasts for about a minute, but sometimes longer.

Any ideas on how to analyze/fix this?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but instead of seeing a frozen screen, its just black for about a minute or so. This just started happening a few days ago. Very irritating.

Comment: How long does it take?  What model of MacBook is it?